# Php phone validation doesn't work

Tags: php, validation, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, required

I'm working with Prestashop 1.6, I'm not really into PHP, but I wanted to make 1 change in website look. In default I have 2 phone inputs: for home and mobile. 
It looks like that:

```
<div style="display: none" class="form-group is_customer_param">
                    <label for="phone">{l s='Home phone'}{if isset($one_phone_at_least) && $one_phone_at_least} <sup>**</sup>{/if}</label>
                    <input type="text" class="text form-control validate" name="phone" id="phone" data-validate="isPhoneNumber" value="{if isset($guestInformations) && isset($guestInformations.phone) && $guestInformations.phone}{$guestInformations.phone}{/if}" />
                </div>
                <div class="{if isset($one_phone_at_least) && $one_phone_at_least}required {/if}form-group">
                    <label for="phone_mobile">{l s='Mobile phone'}{if isset($one_phone_at_least) && $one_phone_at_least} <sup>*</sup>{/if}</label>
                    <input type="text" class="text form-control validate" name="phone_mobile" id="phone_mobile" data-validate="isPhoneNumber" value="{if isset($guestInformations) && isset($guestInformations.phone_mobile) && $guestInformations.phone_mobile}{$guestInformations.phone_mobile}{/if}" />
                </div>
                {if isset($one_phone_at_least) && $one_phone_at_least}
                    {assign var="atLeastOneExists" value=true}
                    <p class="inline-infos required">* Podaj nr telefonu</p>
                {/if}
```

I've made first one not visible, because I thought that one filled field will be enough. And it seems to be. But I can submit a form without entering mobile phone number. Can you see maybe where is problem here? Or maybe how can I make it working?

Example of field which works good, is really required and not paired with another field:

```
    <div class="required form-group">
                        <label for="lastname_invoice">{l s='Last name'} <sup>*</sup></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control validate" id="lastname_invoice" name="lastname_invoice" data-validate="isName" value="{if isset($guestInformations) && isset($guestInformations.lastname_invoice) && $guestInformations.lastname_invoice}{$guestInformations.lastname_invoice}{/if}" />
                    </div>
```

I've tried to validate mobile this way:

```
<div class="required phone_mobile form-group">
                    <label for="phone_mobile">{l s='Mobile phone'} <sup>*</sup></label>
                    <input type="text" class="text form-control validate" name="phone_mobile" id="phone_mobile" data-validate="isPhoneNumber" value="{if isset($guestInformations) && isset($guestInformations.phone_mobile) && $guestInformations.phone_mobile}{$guestInformations.phone_mobile}{/if}" />
                </div>
```

but without success...

Comment: is the standard contact form ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `$one_phone_at_least` variable is not set to `true`. From the back-office, go to **Preferences** > **Customers** and make sure that "Phone number is mandatory" is turned on. That should fix it.

By the way, the `required` class should be used on the `input`, not the `form-group` container. If you made that one change, you could have prevented the user from submitting the form, but if they worked around it to send the data without a phone number, the server would allow it. By following the steps in my first paragraph, the server will also demand that a phone number is set.

Comment: Yes! That's it. thank you. I don't know why this "required" is used on div. Maybe it's used as CSS selector somewhere. Anyway thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Open controllers/front/ContactController.php
in the function "postProcess()"

You can enter such fields required to make that message and to release

to make compulsory the phone number would change

to make compulsory the phone number would add to the list is elseif:

```
} elseif (!(Tools::getValue('phone_mobile')||Tools::getValue('phone'))) {
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('It is mandatory to enter a pleasant phone number.');
}
```